# Calculating the error difference in neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am somewhat new to neural networks and I need some help to understand the basics. I am trying to create a single neuron with two inputs, with a bias and an output.

The process that happens is like this,

```
output = w1 * x + w2 * y + bias * wb
```

So here x and y are the inputs and w1,w2,wb are the weights and bias is 0.5

**After that the output goes through the sigmoid function.**

```
sout = S(output)
```

For testing I am trying to make the neuron act as 'and' and 'or' gates.

So my questions are,

So to calculate the difference between the target and the outputs do I have to run the target(0 or 1) also through a sigmoid function and calculate the difference between them?

or do I just have to calculate the difference between the target (0 or 1) and the output which comes through a sigmoid function?

Also the variation of error in both 'and' and 'or' functions are different as the epoch progresses. The 'and' function error variation is awkward but the 'or' function error variation is acceptable. Why is the 'and' function giving such a wired chart of error going both up and down?

[image: The 'or' error chart]

**The or error chart**

[image: The 'and' error chart]

**The and error chart**

Thanks

Comment: Which error function do you use?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Hi, I posted the code here it's pretty basic code won't take minutes to understand please lemme know where the error I can't seem to locate it, it's in nodejs http://pastie.org/private/2fvceh31ucuurdpkur5zg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delta to calculate is the second one you proposed. You pass your input (x,y) through the network and take the difference between the associated output and the target value (0 or 1). This assumes your are attempting to perform a binary classification task where the target value would be either 0 or 1.

Comment: Thanks @bogatron I added some extra details to the question, can you provide an answer to that as well.

Comment: The `and` error is oscillating between 0 and 0.5. It isn't clear what is happening without seeing your weight update code but I would guess that you either have an error in your weight update formula or your learning rate parameter (if you have one) is too high (i.e., you are over-correcting, which causes your weights to ping-pong back and forth).

Comment: It's very basic code, I posted it here, I can't seem to see any error can you help me to spot an error if one is there http://pastie.org/private/2fvceh31ucuurdpkur5zg

Comment: It appears you are missing a negative sign in the `exp` argument in your sigmoid function (i.e., `num` should be negated) . If you still have problems after that, consider reducing the value of `neta` (maybe to ~ 0.2).